# Make a html table with PHP foreach

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

I try to make a table and fill the cells with data from a MySql DB and foreach :

```
<div class="single mb-5 mt-5">
```

```
<thead>
<tr>
  <th data-sort="string">Titre <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
  <th data-sort="string">Genre <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
  <th data-sort="string">Date de sortie <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
  <th data-sort="string">Casting <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<?php foreach($movie->getMovies() as $m) { ?>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="?p=single&id=<?php echo $m['id']; ?>" class="card-link"><?php echo $m['title']; ?></a></td>
  <td><?php echo $m['genres']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $m['release_date']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $m['release_date']; ?></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function($) { 
  $("#movie_list").stupidtable();
  }); 
</script>
```

There is the result:

[image: table.jpg]

There is enough data to have 21 table rows but there is only one.

Could you tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop only table row not table body, change your foreach loop to this:

```
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach($movie->getMovies() as $m): ?>
      <tr>
          <td><a href="?p=single&id=<?php echo $m['id']; ?>" class="card-link"><?php echo $m['title']; ?></a></td>
          <td><?php echo $m['genres']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $m['release_date']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $m['release_date']; ?></td>
      </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have messed up the table structure, you have added `<tbody>` into the loop. when first loop runs it close the `</body>` and `</table>` rest of the data goes out of structure.

Answer (score 0):

The while statement works for me:

```
<?php

$check = "SELEC * FROM table_name";
$execute = mysqli_query($connection, $check);
$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($elements)) {
   $title = $row['title'];
   $genres = $row['genres'];
   $releaseDate = $row['release_date'];
   $releaseDate = $row['release_date'];

   $i++;
?>
<tbody>
   <tr>
   <td><a href="?p=single&id=<?php echo $m['id']; ?>" class="card-link"><?php echo $m['title']; ?></a></td>
      <td><?php echo $m['genres']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $m['release_date']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $m['release_date']; ?></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<?php } ?>
```